# Existential quantification of typeclass constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass, quantifiers

I am not sure why `ko` does not typecheck.
Is there a particularly enlightening explanation ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Wrap where

class ExpSYM repr where
    lit :: Int -> repr

newtype Wrapped = Wrapped{unWrap :: forall repr. ExpSYM repr => repr}

a = (lit <$> Just 5) :: ExpSYM expr => Maybe expr

ko :: Maybe Wrapped
ko = do v <- a
        return $ Wrapped $ v

ok :: Maybe Wrapped
ok = do v <- Just 5
        let e = lit v
        return $ Wrapped $ e
```

The compiler mentions

```
SO.hs:15:14: error:
    • No instance for (ExpSYM a0) arising from a use of ‘a’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: v <- a
      In the expression:
        do { v <- a;
             return $ Wrapped $ v }
      In an equation for ‘ko’:
          ko
            = do { v <- a;
                   return $ Wrapped $ v }

SO.hs:16:28: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘repr’ with actual type ‘a0’
        because type variable ‘repr’ would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          ExpSYM repr => repr
        at SO.hs:16:18-28
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘v’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘Wrapped $ v’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: return $ Wrapped $ v
    • Relevant bindings include v :: a0 (bound at SO.hs:15:9)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

***Edit :***
Found a nice solution to circumvent this in Oleg's note, which is to specialize the type such that the polymorphism is removed by type application, adding the instance

```
instance ExpSYM Wrapped where
   lit x = Wrapped $ lit x
```

we then have

```
notko :: Maybe Wrapped
notko = do v <- a    
           return $ v -- note the difference. what's the type of a ?

-- and we get all the usual goodies, no silly impredicative error
alsoOk = lit <$> Just 5 :: Maybe Wrapped
```

Comment: What do you mean with "*does not work*". Please provide a compile error/unexpected output, etc.

Comment: I meant typecheck of course. everyone knows after type checking, everything works ;) - (you are right though)

Comment: The error suggests it already goes wrong with the `newtype`, not `ko`/`ok`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ko` would only work if the type of `a` were

```
a :: Maybe (∀ expr . ExpSYM expr => expr)
a = lit <$> Just 5
```

...because only then would you be able to do-unwrap it to obtain the polymorphic value `v :: ∀ expr . ExpSYM expr => expr`. That value must be polymorphic so it can actually be used in `Wrapped`.

But `Maybe (∀ expr . ExpSYM expr => expr)` is an [impredicative type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Impredicative_polymorphism). GHC Haskell doesn't support impredicative types.

OTOH, in `ok`, `v` is just a boring old integer coming from an unspectacular `Just 5 :: Maybe Int`. Only `e` introduces the polymorphism, but does so outside of the `Maybe` monad.

Comment: spot on. thank you. so polymorphism should come last. I have another very counter intuitive example where switching from successive applications g applied to f applied to some value works, while composing functions first and applying to the value fails. a bit frustrating..